# Solving complex numbers equation $z^3 = \overline{z} $

Tags: complex-numbers

We have the following equation:

$$z^3 = \overline{z} $$

I set z to be $z = a + ib$ and since I know that $ \overline{z} = a - ib$. I was trying to solve it by opening the left side of the equation.

$$ z^3 = (a+ib)^3 \Rightarrow $$
$$ [a^2+b^2+i(ab + ba)](a+ib) \Rightarrow $$
$$ a^3 - b^2a - 2b^2a + i (2a^2b + b^2a - b^3) $$

but this is where I got so far and I'm not sure how continue and if my solution so far is even the right way to solve it.

Comment: Use $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\bar z= re^{- i\theta}$

Comment: @Mann by the 're' sign you mean the real number part? with a power of what?

Comment: It's the representation of complex number in polar coordinates. Where $r$ is magnitude of radius vector. $\theta$ tells the rotation.

Comment: You can use $\Rightarrow$ `\Rightarrow$` or $\implies$ `$\implies$`. It definitely looks better than $=>$. However, in this case writing simply $=$ might be better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In polar form, on the modulus side,
$$r^3=r,$$ hence $r=0\lor r=1$.

On the argument side,

$$3\theta=-\theta+2k\pi,$$
hence $\theta=k\pi/2$.

The solutions are $$0,1,i,-1,-i.$$

Comment: Why this downvote, please ?

Comment: A clear and simple answer. Why downvote?

Comment: Good answer, stupid downvote ! So $+1$. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

one of solutions is obviusly $z=0$. For other solutions the simple way is to write $z=re^{ia}$, then
$$
z^3=\bar z\implies |z^3|=|\bar z|=|z|\implies |z|^2=1\implies r=1
$$
now we calculate $a$ by observing that
$$
z^4=z\bar z=1
$$
so you just need to find all $4$-th roots of unity to finish...

Comment: You never really used $re^{ia}$. You've just shown that $\lvert z\rvert^2=1$, and then noticed that $z^4=z\overline z=\lvert z\rvert^2=1$.

Comment: I noticed that for last step to find $a$...

Answer (score 5):

Equating the real & the imaginary parts, $$a^3-3ab^2=a\iff a(a^2-3b^2-1)=0$$

and $$3a^2b-b^3=-b\iff b(3a^2-b^2+1)=0$$

Either $a=0\  \ \  \ (1)$ or $a^2-3b^2-1=0\  \ \  \ (2)$

and either $b=0\  \ \  \ (3)$ or $3a^2-b^2+1=0\  \ \  \ (4)$

Test with

$(1),(3);$

$(1),(4);$

$(2),(3);$

$(2),(4)$

Comment: Hint: (2)-(4) yields $a^2=3b^2+1$ then $8b^2+4=0$ (!)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, That leads to absurdity as $a,b$ are real.

Comment: That's exactly the reason of the exclamation mark.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, $(2),(3)$ also leads to absurdity. But the rest two gives valid solutions, right?

Comment: Er, (2)-(3) leads to $a=\pm1$ I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Multiplyng both sides by $z$ you have:
$$
z^4=|z|^2
$$
Now use the polar form $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 2):

So good, so far.

Now: you want $z^3=\overline z$, therefore $\color{blue}{(a^3−3b^2a)}+i\color{green}{(2a^2b+b^2a−b^3)} =\color{blue}{a}-i\color{green}{b}$.

That gives you two equations with two unknowns.  Solve them

Answer (score 2):

You have a good start. Rewrite equation as $z^3-\bar{z} =0$, now do $z=a+bi$, so we get $$a^3-3b^2a-a+i(3a^2b-b^3-b) = 0$$

Now both the imaginary and the real part must be equal to zero, so we get the following system of equations $$a^3-3b^2a-a=0 \wedge 3a^2b-b^3-b=0$$

Factoring gives:

$$a(a^2-3b^2-1)=0 \wedge b(3a^2-b^2-1)=0$$

So we have four possibilities:

1. $a=0, b=0$
2. $a=0, 3a^2-b^2-1=0$
3. $a^2-3b^2-1=0, b=0$
4. $a^2-3b^2-1=0, 3a^2-b^2-1=0$

---

First one clearly gives $z=0$.

---

Second one: Substitute $a=0$ in to get $b^2-1=0$, so $b=1$ or $b=-1$.

This gives $z=i$ and $z=-i$.

---

Third one: Substitute $b=0$ in to get $a^2-1=0$, so $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

This gives $z=1$ and $z=-1$.

---

Fourth one: Subtract the first equation trice form the second. This gives $8b^2+2=0$, so $b^2+\frac{1}{4}=0$, so $b=\pm\frac{1}{2}i$. This gives no solutions, since we defined $b = \Im(z)$ and it must be real.

---

Conclusion: The solutions are $z=0,1,-1,i,-i$.

Comment: What happened to the solutions $b=\pm i/2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Note we have $b=1/2i$, so that also couts for the real part. So we have $-1/2-1/2=-1$, $-1/2+1/2=0$, $1/2+1/2=1$,

Comment: But what's $a$ and why do you add $\pm1/2\pm1/2$ ?

Comment: a=Re(z), b=Im(z). If b is not real, then the imaginary part moves to the real part.

Comment: Obviously there is a flaw as $\Im(z)$ is a real number and cannot be $\pm i/2$, but you don't answer the question: how do you get the value of $a$ and why do you combine $\pm1/2\pm1/2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust In that case, it is my broken understanding of Im(z). I believe I have once seen that this method gives new solutions, perhaps that was a mistake. I will edit the post. Oh, and, by the way: $a$ was obtained by substituting $b$ in the other equation.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both sides by $z$ (that does not introduce new solutions), $z^4=|z|^2$ is a real number.

Then by the imaginary part,
$$4a^3b-4ab^3=0,$$
$$a=0\lor b=0\lor a^2=b^2.$$

The real part gives,

$$a^4-6a^2b^2+b^4=a^2+b^2$$
which simplifies to 
$$b^4=b^2\lor a^4=a^2\lor-4a^4=2a^2,$$
and it is an easy matter to list the five solutions,

$$\color{green}{(0,0),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)}.$$